# How to delete column from all tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to delete the `ABCDEF` column from all tables of my database. I am trying this code:

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)  

SELECT 
    @SQL = STUFF((SELECT ' DROP column ' + quotename(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + quotename(table_NAME ) +'.ABCDEF;'
FROM
    information_schema.columns 
FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'')

PRINT @SQL

EXECUTE (@SQL)
```

But I am getting an error

> incorrect syntax near column

How to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use an undocumented feature of SQL Server `sys.sp_msforeachtable`. The below script will basically iterate for all the tables in database and `alter` them if required.

```
select '[dbo].['+tab.name+']' name into #table from 
sys.tables tab join sys.columns col on tab.object_id = col.object_id and col.name = 'ABCDEF'

exec sys.sp_msforeachtable 'if exists (select 1 from #table where name = ''?'') 
alter table ?  drop column [ABCDEF]'
```

Answer (score 5):

That's not the right way to drop a column from a table. It should be

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN column_name
```

Build your `dynamic query` something like this:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)=''

SELECT @SQL += 'Alter table ' + Quotename(table_catalog)
               + '.' + Quotename(table_schema) + '.'
               + Quotename(TABLE_NAME) + '  DROP column '
               + Quotename(column_name) + ';'
FROM   information_schema.columns where COLUMN_NAME = 'abcd' -- Here alone mention 
                                                             --the Column to be removed

EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

While dropping the columns from multiple tables, I faced following default constraints error.

> The object 'DF_TableName_ColumnName' is dependent on column 'ColumnName'.

To resolve this, I have to drop all those constraints first, by using following query

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)=''     
SELECT @SQL += 'Alter table ' + Quotename(tbl.name) + '  DROP constraint ' + Quotename(cons.name) + ';'
 FROM SYS.DEFAULT_CONSTRAINTS cons 
 JOIN   SYS.COLUMNS col ON col.default_object_id = cons.object_id
 JOIN   SYS.TABLES tbl ON tbl.object_id = col.object_id
 WHERE  col.[name] IN ('Column1','Column2')

--PRINT @sql
EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

After that, I dropped all those columns by using the answer above.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)='' 
SELECT @SQL += 'Alter table ' + Quotename(table_catalog)+ '.' + Quotename(table_schema) + '.'+ Quotename(TABLE_NAME) 
               + '  DROP column ' + Quotename(column_name) + ';'
FROM   information_schema.columns where COLUMN_NAME IN ('Column1','Column2')  
--PRINT @sql
EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

I posted here in case someone find the same issue.

**Happy Coding!**